# Calling stored procedure from another procedure with where clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, filter

I have a table `tblemployee` with this sample data:

```
srno name      Lastname
------------------------
1    Ibrahim   shaikh
2    ibrahim   mohammed
3    ibrahim   khan
4    paul      haymen
```

And I have a stored procedure `SPGetEmp`. When I execute the procedure like this:

```
SPGetEmp 'ibrahim',''
```

it is returning this result data:

```
srno name      Lastname
------------------------
1    Ibrahim   shaikh
2    ibrahim   mohammed
3    ibrahim   khan
```

Now I want to filter the data from another stored procedure, like now I want to filter the data with last name, for example `'shaikh'`.

Result should be:

```
srno name      Lastname
-----------------------
1    Ibrahim   shaikh
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to insert the results into a temp table or variable, and then execute a `SELECT` query with the desired `WHERE` clause.  For example:

```
DECLARE @results TABLE(
      srno int
    , name nvarchar(30)
    , Lastname nvarchar(30)
);

INSERT INTO @results
    EXEC SPGetEmp 'ibrahim','';

SELECT srno, name, Lastname 
FROM @results
WHERE Lastname = 'shaikh';
```

Consider adding the criteria to the `SPGetEmp` proc as that will perform better if often executed.

Comment: `create proc testingemp
as
begin
DECLARE TABLE @results(
      srno int
      name nvarchar(30)
    , Lastname nvarchar(30)
);
INSERT INTO @results
    EXEC SPGetEmp 'ibrahim','';

SELECT srno, name, Lastname 
FROM @results
WHERE Lastname = 'shaikh';
end`

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure testingemp, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure testingemp, Line 9
Must declare the table variable "@results".
Must declare the table variable "@results".


I am getting this error

Comment: @IbrahimShaikh, I fixed the typo.

Comment: #Temp versus @variable tables.  Former can use statistics the latter cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter or join the result of stored procedure becase what it returns is not a table even if you "see" it as a table.

But you can rewrite it as an inline table valued function and then you can use it as a "parameterized" view, i.e. you can select from it, filter it, join it, like this:

```
create function dbo.ufn_GetEmp (@name varchar(100))  
returns table  
as  
return   
(  
    select srno, name, Lastname
    from tblemployee
    where name = @name
);  
go 

select *
from  dbo.ufn_GetEmp('ibrahim')
where lastname = 'shaikh';
```